# How to graph in Cylindrical coordinates in 3D

Tags: plotting

I need help figuring out how to plot in cylindrical coordinates. I read that `CylindricalPlot3D` was replaced with `RevolutionPlot3D`. Here is my function:

```
Integrate[ r^3*(Cos[ θ])^2, { θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2 r}]
```

> ```
> (2 π)/5
> ```

when I try `RevolutionPlot3D` I get:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[ r^3*(Cos[θ])^2, { θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2 r}]
```

> ```
> RevolutionPlot3D::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {z,0,2 r}) beyond position 3 
> in RevolutionPlot3D[r^3 Cos[θ]^2,{ θ,0,2 π},{r,0,1},{z,0,2 r}]. 
> An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
> ```

Comment: @Kuba I wonder if people take the time to reformat code would it be too much extra to replace i -> I? Sorry for nitpicking, but you inter-edited my edit which I discarded :) Also `\[Theta]` to `θ`.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know what code reformat i was supposed to use. i'm trying to plot this triple integral volume.

Comment: @IstvánZachar you are right, I was not paying attention. About greek letters, I replace them only when I'm on pc with the addon for it, now I'm not :)

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, a tidy edit is a good edit. Now I go on to find another stackexchanger to bully :) User10977: You could format code blocks with CTRL+K, quotes with CTRL+Q. Look up help.

Comment: oh ok. anyway, any idea why it's not working

Comment: @user10977, what are you trying to visualise, the function `r^3 Cos[θ]^2` or the volume over which you have integrated it?

Comment: related [calculating volume](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27649/5478)

Comment: Your syntax is not valid for `CylindricalPlot3D` either.  Do you have existing code you are trying to run?  If not, why the reference to `CylindricalPlot3D`?

Answer (score 1):

`RevolutionPlot3D` accepts only a  maximum of two variables for iteration in the form `RevolutionPlot3D[f, {t, ...}, {θ, ...}]`. Nevertheless, one can manipulate the third:

```
Manipulate[RevolutionPlot3D[r^3*(Cos[θ])^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {z, 0, 2 r}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, SphericalRegion -> True, Mesh -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}, {-2, 2}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}],
 {{r, π/2}, 0.001, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you very much for the response but that's not what it is supposed to look like. it needs to be the solid volume solid that lies within the cylinder x^2+y^2=1, above the plain z=0 ,and below the cone z^2=4x^2+4y^2. i converted to cylindrical coordinates (z,r,theta)

Comment: @user10977 So you want this `RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && z^2 < 4 x^2 + 4 y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity@.3]` but done with `RevolutionPlot3D`?

Comment: Yes yes thank you that is exactly the shape i need you are the best. It does not need to be with RevolutionPlot3D. I should have explained myself more clearly. I'm looking to create a graph with that solid/volume that i can manipulate the variables just like this example: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/data/001571/0007/ExploringCylindricalCoordinates/ExploringCylindricalCoordinates-source.nb

Comment: here is the page it comes from http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExploringCylindricalCoordinates/