# Revolving the area between two functions about an axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, rotation

I'm trying to graph the revolution of the area between two functions about an axis, but I'm new to Mathematica, and not sure how to proceed. My area is defined by

```
Plot[{x^2,x},{x,-5,5}, Filling -> {1->{2}}]
```

Just to clarify, the figure I'm looking is 3-dimensional, and could loosely be called a toroid.

How could I model this in 3D?

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27649/5478)

Comment: @Kuba somewhat related; I'm just trying to graph the toroid (and not the actual curves), not calculate the area.

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[Plot3D[{(x x + y y), -Sqrt[(x x + y y)]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
            RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 25 &)], 
     RevolutionPlot3D[{5, t}, {t, -5, 25}, Mesh -> None, 
                      PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]